# How to display a different field than `id` in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: strapi

I would like to implement tags in strapi. — a project can have multiple tags, but I would also like to be able to find projects by tag.

so I created:

[image]

[image]

but in my projects, it displays the tag ids. how can I make it so that it shows the tag *name* instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by "configure the view" under the pulldown on the page where you create the content. This is feature since the last view releases.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Here is a short video to see it in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzipS2CePRc&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=5&t=0s